# Given two variables X and Y, what is the Euclidean Distance?

Tags: geometry

Could someone show me their workings to this question? I got the same answer as the practise exam but I'm not confident to whether it's just coincidence or not:

Given the two variables: X and Y

X = [1.5, 3.0, 2.5, 2.0, 0.0]
Y = [3.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0]

and the regression model y=2x+1

What is the Euclidean distance between X and Y?

A) 2.0
B) 8.0
C) 4.0
D) 16.0

Answer: C

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. How can we know if it's a coincidence or not if you don't share how you got to this answer?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call $X$ and $Y$ variables if you have assigned them specific values.  I suspect the word you want here is *vectors*, in that the sequence of real numbers shown are *component* entries of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.  Then it makes sense to ask about the Euclidean distance between them.

Comment: @hardmath that was my thoughts but I didn't write the question, perhaps that's what threw my confidence in the answer

Comment: I think your reading of the problem should be conditioned by the surrounding material you've studied in connection with it.  Such context will help Readers respond appropriately for the level of your studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Euclidean distance between $X$ and $Y$ is $\|X-Y\|=\|(-2,2,2,2,0)\|=\sqrt{(-2)^2+2^2+2^2+2^2+0^2}=\sqrt{16}=4$.